# Registry mismatch Get-NetAdapter

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I took an image from another Windows 10 PC and setup a new PC with this image.
Now I have the problem, that I change interface alias:

```
Rename-NetAdapter -InterfaceAlias "SwitchLan" -NewName "test"
```

and it says that the value  "test" is already there.

```
Rename-NetAdapter : {Object Exists} An attempt was made to create an object and the object name already existed. 
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-NetAdapter -InterfaceAlias "SwitchLan" -NewName "test"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (MSFT_NetAdapter... "PC-Name"):ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter) [ 
   Rename-NetAdapter], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 698,Rename-NetAdapter
```

In the registry, I deleted the entry "test", but still, even when I change the entry "SwitchLAN" to "test", I can see in the Windows overview the interface "test", but when I put `ipconfig` in the commandlet I get the entry "SwitchLan", the same with PowerShell `Get-NetAdapter`.

Reboot didn't work.

Where can this value be stored, what happens here?

Also, when I want to change "test" to "test2" it says that there is no "test" interface, but when I want to change "SwitchLan" to "test" it says "test" is already there.

On the previous Image, there was an interface with the name "test".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Device-Manager -> show hidden devices -> then uninstall all adapters which aren't connected to the system anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the already existing, but hidden, network adapter from your image, named "test" using something like this:

```
Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden -Name "test" | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "Obsolete"
```

Then you can give the name "test" to your new network adapter.

Comment: Hello,
An hour ago, i found another solution for the Problem:
In the Device-Manager -> show hidden devices -> then uninstall all adapters which aren't connected to the system anymore, after this i was able to change the name.
But I will get another PC with the image in the near future again and try this.